# Reference project to WCF best practices

Tags: .net, asp.net, wpf, wcf

For WPF, there's the Microsoft Patterns & Practices's [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) project.

> Prism provides guidance designed to
>   help you more easily design and build
>   rich, flexible, and easy-to-maintain
>   Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   desktop applications, Silverlight Rich
>   Internet Applications (RIAs), and
>   Windows Phone 7 applications

I was wondering whether a similar project (reference implementation) intended for software developers building WCF applications exists.

In our main internal project (a .Net WinForms rich client app), we don't talk directly with the database but instead fetch and update data with ASP.Net web-services that we also control. Our current setup is giving us some bottlenecks.
For a new smallish project, we want to try WCF.

Objective question: Where do I find a not-too-basic WCF reference project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing like Prism provided by Microsoft. WCF usually makes only thin layer on top of other logic.

You can check this guidance for Visual Studio:

- [Web Service Software Factory](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/)
- [Web Service Software Factory Contrib](http://wssfcontrib.codeplex.com/)

You can also check different articles about best practices:

- [WCF Security Guidance Project](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/)
- [Guidelines and best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731197.aspx)
- [Security Guidance and Best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731983.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can find some targeted examples in the Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Training Kit.

It contains several projects demonstrating key features. It is sometimes more relevant than a big project containing to much information.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=752CB725-969B-4732-A383-ED5740F02E93&displaylang=en